# Разбить xml файл для загрузки в вп

Tags: wordpress, xml

Есть xml файл с весом 3.7гб, сервер на сколько я понял принимает максимум 512 мб. Каким образом проще всего его разбить без потери структуры и чтобы все нормально импортировалось в wp

Comment: Разбить вряд ли получится. К тому же, не видя структуры xml, точно ответить невозможно. Кроме того, сайт упадёт при импорте по лимиту времени. Файл надо качать по ftp. Импортировать через wp-cli или запуском своего php файла из консоли сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте плагин [WP All Import](http://www.wpallimport.com/), специально предназначенный для импорта больших файлов.

Вам может хватить и бесплатной версии, размещенной в официальном репозитории wp.org.